# Trying to access debug logs on WeMo smart plug

Tags: smart-home, smart-plugs, wemo

I have been experimenting with my WeMo IoT smart plug, along with PyWeMo, an API designed to allow for low-level access to the plug.

I would like to access debug logs made by the plug, but the link provided by the API does not work, and I cannot find any documentation on how to get to these logs.

Does anyone have any experience with finding these debug logs?

Comment: What logs? A link to the details of the API would be helpful as I'm not aware of any offical docs for the on device API